# Change SampleData columns to double instead of int

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, datagrid, blend

Solved:

Solution was to edit the next line in the XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Exp,StringFormat ={}{0:n3}}" Header="data"/>
```

I have made a DataGrid in blend.
The DataGrid will contain few columns which one of them will be image and one of them a number.

However, when binding data the options are like this:

[image]

Now, when i try to edit the column data and instert number like 150.5 i get an error because it was meant to be int.

Is there a way to change it so it will accept double type?

Thanks you.

Comment: What code have you written for this?

Comment: haven't wrote any code it. i just draw in blend and there is an option ot insert data manually.